# how to perform PSTN in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi I want to perform a call through PSTN which means the call should be like the normal call which I used by my iPhone not the network call using wifi or the 3g data connection. I am trying to find any helpful link to go through this problem but still dint find any helpful link. If anyone have any solution for the same please tell me. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a tel: url with `[UIApplication openURL:]`

Comment: @Paulw11 but this call go through the wifi or the data connection, if I am not wrong???

Comment: No, it will prompt the user to confirm they want to call the number and then open the phone application to place the call using the cellular network

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please suggest the whole code related to this if you are sure that this will invoke your default dialer screen and use your sim to call the number not the network(wifi,3g)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke the 'phone' application by creating a `tel:` URL and passing it to the `openURL` `UIApplication` class method. This will display an alert asking the user to confirm that they want to place the call and then make the call using the cellular service.

```
NSURL phoneURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:5551234"];
[UIApplication openURL:phoneURL];
```